# Can 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' driver be shipped to client as dll?

Tags: c#, ms-access, 64-bit

I have created project in `C# .net 4.0` to read xls file.

I am facing issue of `"'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine"` on `64 bit Win7 OS`. After searching found I have to install `AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe`.

So I removed `32 bit` version of MS office and then installed `AccessDatabaseEngine_x64`. My code worked fine.

Now question, when I have to send `exe` to client, does client have install `AccessDatabaseEngine_x64` or I can use some dlls of AccessDatabaseEngine copied to solution and it will work fine?

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through this issue once.

Depending upon Microsoft office version your client is having, he has to install `AccessDatabaseEngine_x64`.

Or you can simply make DB file in the office version which your client is already having and then send the solution to client.

Comment: So there no way we can avoid installation of AccessDatabaseEngine_x64 on server?

Comment: @TanajiKamble nope, kahich margg nahi tyala,,tumhala karawach lagel,,nahitar client kade konta version aahe paha MS Office ch,,aani tya pramane Access file banawa DB chi